# Add Images in WebForm Dropdown list

Tags: webforms

Using Drupal 7 and WebForm Module (version 7.x-4.2). How would I go about adding images, next to text, in a dropdown listbox?

Is this even possible?

I have a dropdown with a list of products and I'd like to add an image next to the name.

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be better to have that form coded by hand where you can turn your  list into a set of divs with a jQuery library, eg. http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/ddSlick

Or, you can set a background image to each option with CSS (which kinds of takes a bit of time depending on how much options you have in your select list):

```
select option[value="your_value"] {
  background-image: url(your_image.png);
}
```

Comment: Thanks crzpiot, How would I do the second option within the webform module or do I need to edit the raw code?

Comment: I have 14 Products in the dropdown

Comment: Actually, I think it would be best to change to Radio Buttons with small image (click opens larger popup). Is there a WebForm plugin that allow adding an image next to a Radio Button?

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_select_image

Comment: Thanks, but found out WebForm Select Image does not work with Conditionals, so looking for another option.